# Scale down image AND frame

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to scale an image down, and have some text next to it. Logically I tried `scaleEffect` like this:

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Image("anno")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 180, height: 280, alignment: .center)
        .clipped()
        .scaleEffect(0.8, anchor: .bottomLeading)
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Title")
            .font(.headline)
        Text("Description")
    }
    .layoutPriority(2)
}
```

But it seems to only scale the image and not the frame around it, which means it occupy the same space as when not scaled, and the text can take the freed space.

[image: example picture]

How can I scale the view and not only the picture inside it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scaling image, decrease frame, the image will scale to it automatically

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Image("anno")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 150, height: 250, alignment: .center)     // << for example
        .clipped()
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      // ... other code
```

Comment: Is this the only solution? I'd like to not do that if possible, since actually the image and it's modifiers comes from another view that I use at multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `ScaleEffect` applies on the content, you should calculate the scaled frame and apply the new frame on the `view`. You can use the `scaledFrame` for that:

```
Image("anno")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .scaledFrame(width: 180, height: 280, alignment: .bottomLeading, scale: 0.8) // <- This line
    .clipped()
```

With the help of this extension:

```
extension View {
    public func scaledFrame(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, alignment: Alignment = .center, scale: CGFloat) -> some View {
        self.frame(width: width * scale,
                   height: height * scale,
                   alignment: alignment)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, using a frame with lower width and height seems to be the only solution to shrink a view. but because I reuse a custom view with the image, simply adding `frame` will cut the image. This is where `scaleEffect` comes in

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    CustomImageView()
        .scaleEffect(0.7, anchor: .center)
        .frame(width: 126, height: 196) // original width&height * 0.7 (the scale rate)

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Title")
             .font(.headline)
        Text("Description")
    }
    .layoutPriority(2)
}
```